# why may came before july

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get month names in descending order but I am getting may before july and then february. Why is this?I am using codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select("MONTHNAME(`published_date`) as month");
$this->db->group_by("MONTH(`published_date`)");
$this->db->where("status", "yes");
$this->db->where("YEAR(`published_date`)", $year);
$this->db->where("category_id", $id);
$this->db->order_by("MONTHNAME(`published_date`)", 'DESC');
$result = $this->db->get('tbl_news')->result();
```

In my database I have feb, may and july saved as date. But I am getting may , july and feb instead of july, may, feb.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: because, it is using ascii value of month

Comment: show the actual output.

Comment: You order by month name, M > J > F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
$this->db->order_by("MONTHNAME(`published_date`)", 'DESC');
```

use

```
$this->db->order_by("`published_date`", 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->db->order_by("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `published_date`)", 'DESC');
```

instead of

```
$this->db->order_by("MONTHNAME(`published_date`)", 'DESC');
```